# How do you iterate through distinct values of a column in a large Pyspark Dataframe? .distinct().collect() raises a large task warning

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to iterate through all of the distinct values in column of a large Pyspark Dataframe. When I try to do it using `.distinct().collect()` it raises a "task too large" warning even if there are only two distinct values. 
 Warning message:

```
20/01/13 20:39:01 WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 0 contains a task of very large size (201 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.
```

Here is some sample code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Basics').getOrCreate()
length = 200000

data = spark.createDataFrame([[float(0) for x in range(3)] for x in range(length)], ['a', 'b', 'c'])

data.select("a").distinct().collect()
# This code produces this warning
```

How can you iterate through distinct values in a column of a large Pyspark Dataframe without running into memory issues?

Comment: do you get the same error if you try to run `df.select("*").limit(1).collect()`?

Comment: Yes. I get the same warning when running that line.

Answer (score 2):

As you already know,`.collect()` is not a best practice. Because, it's an action which transfer all the data from executors to the driver. The problem is when you have a large dataset, the Spark executors sent a large amount of serialized data to the driver and THEN do the collection of the 2 rows. You can also take a look to the [TaskSetManager](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/TaskSetManager.scala) which produces the warning.

In a high level, a work around for your problem could be to exchange memory with disk.You can write your dataframe with distinct values in one csv and then read it again line by line with Python or Pandas*:

```
data.select("a").distinct().coalesce(1).write.csv("temp.csv")
# Specifically, it's a directory with one csv.
```

With this solution you will not have any problem with memory.

*There are a lot of solutions about how to read a large CSV with Python or Pandas.

Comment: But since there are only 2 distinct values, shouldn't .collect() work? A small original dataframe with only 2 distinct values does not throw this warning. However, when you have a large original dataframe with only 2 distinct values the error is thrown. Why does the size of the original dataframe matter?

Comment: The warning message is from TaskSetManager as you can see. If we search in the class in the [source Scala code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/TaskSetManager.scala), we find the message in line 448. As you can see in the if statement your task exceeds the serialized memory limit. Because, when you have a large dataset, the Spark executors sent a large amount of data to the driver and THEN do the collection of the 2 rows

Comment: @Jimmy I edit my answer based on your nice comment, and my comment above. Is it clear now?

Comment: So I tried this fix and it does not help. When I run this code, the warning still persists. "data.select("a").distinct().coalesce(1).write" is fine but ".csv("temp.csv") triggers the same warning. Any ideas?

Comment: @ggeop the code that you mentioned is responsible for the task size not the memory management. The method `dequeueTask ` is responsible for the serialisation and the execution of the tasks.